# PUT method mongoose model

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Have this code. Want to chanche chek field.

```
apiRoutes.put('/intake/:id', function(req, res)  {
      var id = req.params.id;
      Intake.findById(id, function(err, intake) {
          if (err)res.send(err);
            if (intake.check == false) {intake.check = true;}
            else {intake.check = false;}
            intake.save(function(err) {
            if (err) {return res.json({success: false, msg: 'Error'});}
          res.json({success: true, msg: 'Successful update check state.'});
        });
      })
    });
```

Recieve this error
        if (check != false) {intake.check = false;}
            ^

ReferenceError: check is not defined

Answer (score 1):

You might not find an intake with that `id`. You should first check to see if any `intake` is returned at all.  Wrap an `if(intake)` around it to catch that exception.

An error is only returned if there's an actual error. If no intake is found, then `findById` will just return an empty object `{}`.  So, you'll get an error if you try to check a field of an empty object.

Try:

```
  Intake.findById(id, function(err, intake) {
      if (err) {res.send(err); return;}
      if (intake) {
        if (intake.check == false) {intake.check = true;}
        else {intake.check = false;}
      } else {
         res.send("No intake found.");
      }
```

Comment: That would send two responses back when `err` is defined (the original code does the same: it doesn't return from the function when an error has occurred and the error response is sent).

Comment: The if...else block used to change the check status is not necessary... intake.check = !intake.check;